# Typescript React `isValidElement` type-guard not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a tooltip component implemented like this (I have simplified it), which can be used in two different ways by passing a value to `tooltip` prop, either it will be a JSX element or a callback function that returns a `ReactElement` eventually:

```
import { isValidElement, ReactNode, useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { Portal } from 'react-portal';

interface ChildrenProps {
    onHide: () => void;
    onShow: () => void;
}

type TooltipCallback = (onHide: () => void) => ReactNode;

export interface Props {
    tooltip: ReactNode | TooltipCallback;
    children: (props: ChildrenProps) => ReactNode;
}

export function Tooltip({ children, tooltip }: Props) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const onHide = useCallback(() => {
        setShow(false);
    }, []);

    const onShow = useCallback(() => {
        setShow(true);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {children({ onHide, onShow })}
            <Portal>
                {show && tooltip !== null && tooltip !== undefined && (
                    <div className="tooltip">
                        {/* TS complains here */}
                        {isValidElement(tooltip) ? tooltip : tooltip(onHide)}
                    </div>
                )}
            </Portal>
        </>
    );
}
```

Usage by passing a callback function to `tooltip`:

```
<Tooltip
    tooltip={(onHide) => (
        <div>
            <span>
                In this tooltip, the only way to close it is by clicking the close button in the tooltip
            </span>
            <button onClick={onHide}>close</button>
        </div>
    )}
>
    {({ onShow }) => <span onMouseOver={onShow}>Some text that triggers tooltip</span>}
</Tooltip>
```

Usage by passing a `ReactElement` to `tooltip`:

```
<Tooltip
    tooltip={
        <span>This is a tooltip that will be closed when goes away when your mouse leaves</span>
    }
>
    {({ onShow, onHide }) => (
        <span onMouseLeave={onHide} onMouseOver={onShow}>
            Some text that triggers tooltip
        </span>
    )}
</Tooltip>;
```

But typescript is complaining about it:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactNodeArray | TooltipCallback' are callable.
    Type 'string' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

However, I assumed since I have the `isValidElement(tooltip)` check, then it is guaranteed that type of the tooltip is not `string` | `number` | `{}` | `ReactNodeArray` when trying to render the tooltip with callback function in the else clause.

How do I fix this TS error?